# Why can't I unmask mongod.service?

Tags: 18.04, systemd, services, mongodb

Running `sudo service mongod start` yields `Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service is masked.`

Running `systemctl list-unit-files` indeed shows

```
mongod.service                                                            masked         
mongodb.service                                                           enabled
```

Running `sudo systemctl unmask mongod` gives no errors, but does not change anything either.

I checked for a symlink at `file /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` but it is `empty`.

I also tried removing `mongod.service` and recreating it.

Does anyone have any advice on what else to try?

Comment: Looks like you have both `mongod` and `mongodb`. According to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76342/difference-between-mongod-and-mongodb-upstart-jobs/76361), the `mongodb` name was used up to version 2.4 and changed to `mongod` with version 2.6. Maybe the `mongodb` unit blocks the `mongod` unit in some way. Have you tried to disable or remove the `mongodb` unit?

Comment: Thanks, does not make a difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `systemctl enable mongod.service`. That might work.

Comment: That command too gives me the error `Unit file /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service is masked.`